# How to hardCode key for Redis Cache in Java in Spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

I am trying to use single redis cache for storing the response of 2 Webservices- one is POST and one is GET. For GET service there is no request parameter against which I can store the response of Webservice in Redis, when I try to store it with hardcoded Key it gives me below error.

```
null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?) Builder[public java.util.Map com.getResponse() throws com.adapter.framework.assetserviceadaptor.exception.ServiceExceptions] caches=[redis-cache] | key='#AssetCache' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
```

This is how I am trying to store GET service response

```
@Cacheable(value="redis-cache",key ="#AssetCache")
public Map<String, AssetDetailBO> getAssetsResponse() throws COAssetServiceExceptions {
    try {
        log.info("---- CO_STAGE=[ Caching Service ] ---- ");
        return mergingBrokerageAndMutulFund(assetServiceImpl.getAssetResponse());
    } catch (ServiceExceptions e) {
        log.info("---- CO_STAGE=[ Exception while Calling Assets Adapter For COT ] ---- " 
        + e.getErrorMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This is how I am storing POST service response, this is working fine.

```
@Cacheable(value="redis-cache",key ="#customerId")
public CustomerDTO retriveCustomerdetails( String customerId, String modelId, 
  String requestId) throws COException {
CustomerInfo csDTO;
try {
    csDTO = csDTOAdapterImpl.
    getCustomerDetails(customerId);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return csDTO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Cacheable` without the value and other properties like `@Cacheable("all-students")`

Example:

```
@GetMapping("/student/{id}")
@Cacheable(value = "post-single", key = "#id")
public Student findStudentById(@PathVariable String id) {
    System.out.println("Searching by ID  : " + id);
    return studentService.getStudentByID(id);
}

@GetMapping("/students")
@Cacheable("all-students")
public List<Student> getAllStudents() {

    List<Student> _ = new ArrayList<>();
    _.add(studentService.getStudentByID("1"));
    return _;
}
```

Comment: I have to access GET service response in another boot application which is in same space, how to access it there without any key ?

Answer (score 0):

Set constant key without # like this:

```
@Cacheable(value="redis-cache",key ="'AssetCache'")
public Map<String, AssetDetailBO> getAssetsResponse() throws COAssetServiceExceptions {
    try {
        log.info("---- CO_STAGE=[ Caching Service ] ---- ");
        return mergingBrokerageAndMutulFund(assetServiceImpl.getAssetResponse());
    } catch (ServiceExceptions e) {
        log.info("---- CO_STAGE=[ Exception while Calling Assets Adapter For COT ] ---- " 
        + e.getErrorMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
```